# How to differentiate between console.error output and thrown exception in Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, web-console

I am creating a *Chrome Extension* with the help of an *API*. It happened that the API was not responding for a particular query, so, I checked out the console (extension's popup console) and found some error messages. All I could not figure out was whether it was a `console.error` or a thrown `Exception`. Is there a **general way** to figure this out just by looking at the console messages or if not then without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the text is different. Try it yourself.

[image]